# Managing Facebook comments with unregistered users

Tags: facebook, comments, facebook-connect

I have a website at [Flickwit](http://www.flickwit.com). The website has the option to login by email registration or Facebook Connect. The issue that I have is that if users are already logged into Facebook in a previous browser session, then they will be able to post comments on the website even though they are not logged in to the application.

This is a problem since I cannot record the comment against a registered user - it would be unethical since they have not officially registered.
What are my options here insofar as maintaining user trust. Should I disconnect the FB comments so that they are forced to log in to post comments or would it be acceptable to (when the user comments) to auto-connect them - in this case they would go through the usual FB registration process and this would purely be a suggestion from the application.
Any other ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When they register for the application, they should be (depending on your wording etc.) agreeing that their posts on the site will show their facebook name.

So they have **already given permission to post with their name**, and if from that point they post a comment, it's reasonable to show their name when they post.

I'm not sure of the technical feasibility of this, but if they aren't logged in when they post, you could prompt them with a warning that their post will show their facebook name.

---

However, before you get into all of that, you have to decide what you really want to achieve with comments.  Some people may not want to post comments with their real name, so if you force people to use their name, many users will simply not comment. You will however generally get better quality comments.

How is commenting a critical part of what you want to achieve?  Once you work that out, you will be able to better make decisions about anonymous commenting.